# Max duration for a selenium webdriver test

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to indicate a max test duration for Selenium Webdriver, and/or if a test runs longer than a certain amount of time that it can be marked as failed and move on to the next test?

Comment: Can someone update the title for me, I cant edit it. It should be duration, not duraton :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided much details about the framework you use. I use `testng`. It has an option `timeOut` in milliseconds.

```
@Test(timeOut=180000)
public void timeoutTest(){
       Thread.sleep(180005); // the test fails
}
```

Comment: I am using XUnit.net which does not have this feature in the latest version

Comment: I just checked this - looks like it was intentionally removed - https://xunit.github.io/docs/test-migration.html